# Unable to install python3.7.x in mac

Tags: macos, python-3.7

I am pretty new in `mac version 12.6` . I tried to install python 3.7 in my mac for trying out some legacy project but I am unable to.

I tried two was downloading the `.pkg` file from `python.org` and also by `pyenv`

While the `.pkg` says successfully installed and `pyenv versions` gives me `3.7.13` .

While trying `python3.7` or `python3` from `terminal` I am getting

```
% python3
zsh: killed     python3
% python3.7
zsh: killed     python3.7
```

But my other versions working fine like

```
% python3.9
Python 3.9.13 (v3.9.13:6de2ca5339, May 17 2022, 11:37:23) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How to fix this isssue.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use pyenv to install and manage Python versions. (You can install it using Homebrew)

1- pyenv install 3.7.0

#To see the list of the Python versions 
2- pyenv versions

#To set the newly installed version as the default 
3- pyenv global 3.7.0

Now, run python3 --version
if the output is NOT 3.7.0 then you need to add the following lines to your .zsh or .zshrc file:

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv" 
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH" 
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

and finally update your .zsh or .zshrc file: 
source .zshrc 
 or 
 source .zsh